# How to resume large file upload (which utilizes chunking)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, chunking

I am looking at using this file upload process in my asp.net MVC website. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830704/Gigabit-File-uploads-Over-HTTP?fid=1870992

It's working great so far. I can see the file being uploaded in chunks (on the server). Essentially they are placed in my upload directory in a directory that has the file name. In that directory, I see the chunks, such as `"LargeFile.00000001.csv.tmp", "LargeFile.000000002.csv.tmp",` etc....

If the upload is canceled I can still see the chunks on the server. Question: How can I "resume" the upload later on?

I could look at the folder name and file chunk names and decipher where I left off.